# Can I use Spatial data in Neo4j from .NET?

Tags: .net, neo4j, spatial

Does anybody have any any information (or preferably examples/tutorials) about spatial access to Neo4j from .NET?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think Neo4jClient has a geospatial library, but you can install the [geospatial server plugin](https://github.com/neo4j/spatial#using-the-neo4j-spatial-server-plugin) and use REST calls to interact with it like any other part of Neo4j server.

Comment: Thanks for that. I thought as much, but didn't want to invent a wheel if there was another already available.